# HXCPP Profiler won't create log file

Tags: profiling, profiler, haxe, hxcpp

I am using Haxe for a game and compiling for the C++ target using HXCPP. I am trying to get the built-in profiler to work (`cpp.vm.Profiler`), but I cannot get it to create a dump file. My code is as simple as that :

```
if(Input.check(Key.P))
    cpp.vm.Profiler.start("profiler.txt");
if(Input.check(Key.M))
    cpp.vm.Profiler.stop();
```

I use HaxePunk for the input, and I assert that the profiler calls are indeed being executed (I made sure using a couple `trace` calls). I use defines `HXCPP_STACK_TRACE` and `HXCPP_PROFILER` for the compilation.

Am I doing anything wrong, or missing anything ?

EDIT : here is some code that when compiled using `haxe -D HXCPP_PROFILER -D HXCPP_STACK_TRACE -main Main -cpp test`, doesn't actually create any noticeable "profiler.txt" file :

```
class Main
{
    static public function main()
    {
        var bleh = haxe.Timer.stamp();
        cpp.vm.Profiler.start("profiler.txt");
        while(haxe.Timer.stamp() - bleh < 5.)
        {
            // Do something I guess
            Math.cos(haxe.Timer.stamp());
        }
        cpp.vm.Profiler.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relevant bug report to hxcpp: [#580](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/issues/580).

Apparently this was fixed on 17 May 2017 in [this commit](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/pull/594/commits/66224f7ad61dc5ed3b828ce3a433e91194d20f2a). The fix should be in the next hxcpp version after 3.4.64.

Comment: Yeah that's my commit haha.

Comment: Hah, I should've seen that :) Thank you for the fix!